# How can i refresh the list of bluetooth devices in java

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth, localization

I am trying to make an android application about localization, i am trying however to make a list of Bluetooth devises found by my smartphone and refresh that lists information every 10 seconds. I want to do that because I am also recording the signal strength (RSSI) and want to record when a beacon is getting out of range when moved or the signal is getting weaker. So refreshing the list will help with that. I have provided some of my code below.

```java
@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
    }
```

```java
    private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int rssid = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
                listAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n" + " RSSI: " + rssid + "dBm");
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                scanningButton.setText("Scan Bluetooth Devices");
            }else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                scanningButton.setText("Scanning in progress ...");
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

use a listview then call  `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter object

Comment: I have already done that but it doesn't refresh the information in the list. Getting a string object in the ListView and change it according to getting weaker rssi or the connection is getting lost.